# How to set up a static IP address for my home server (LAN)

Tags: ip, lan, webserver, ip-address, static-ip

I want to set up a home server, and I need to assign my computer a **local** static IP address. I do not want a public one, just one for my local network, so it doesn't cost money. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answer, but it is entirely possible your router does not have the facility for Reserved Addressing (associate computer NIC MAC with Router IP address.

If this is the case for you, determine the DCHP range of the router and assign your computer a static IP outside of that range. That works also and I use the latter approach in my home office.

Local Static IP addresses are normally set up in the Network Card, TCP/IP properties.  Set up IP, gateway (Router) and DNS address (from your ISP).  The exact setup depends on operating system but the above general instructions cover it.

Comment: How can I assign myself an IP address?

Comment: I amended my answer to provide the methodology.

Answer (score 1):

Static internal addresses are set in your router, using the MAC address of that device's NIC (network interface card) - you'd need to check your router's manual as to how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The simplest is just to set the host IP to a static one that does not conflict with any other one handed by your local network.

The exact command differs depending on which operating system you have but for OpenSUSE you have to edit a file called /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0 and simply set the IP address and netmask you want:

IPADDR='192.168.0.222/24'

Alternately, most modern routers and gateway support *Static DHCP* which is DCHP which simply always sets the same IP address based on the MAC address of a device. Again, the interface differs but look for something that says *Reserve Address* or *Static DHCP* or something similar.

One most of my routers, except the current one, it there was a page in setup where I could simply enter both the static IP and the MAC address. On the latest router, you have to let it be assigned dynamically once and then it gives you a toggle option to *Reserve IP* which you can then edit and takes effect on the next reboot.